# All lines except the last one inside of the for each loop are being skipped

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph-traversal

I am currently writing a recursion algorithm that traverses between nodes (DFT).
But there is something really weird happening, my for each loop is skipping a couple of lines inside of it but only printing out what comes after the if statement inside it.

This is what my Main.java looks like

```
g.addNode("A");
g.addNode("B");
g.addNode("E");
g.addEdge("A", "B");
g.addEdge("A", "E");


g.traverseDepthFirst("A");
```

Very simple, just adding nodes then connected them to eachother (addEdge).

Now this is where things get really weird, in my recursion methods.

```
public void traverseDepthFirst(String root) {
    var node = nodes.get(root);
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    traverseDepthFirst(node, new HashSet<>());
}

private void traverseDepthFirst(Node root, Set<Node> visited) {
    System.out.println("Node: " + root);
    visited.add(root);
    System.out.println("Visited: " + visited);

    for (var node : adjacencyList.get(root)) {
        System.out.println("I happened!");
        System.out.println(root + " contains " + adjacencyList.get(root));
        System.out.println("Node from adjacencyList: " + node);
        if (!visited.contains(node)) {
            System.out.println("Happened!");
            traverseDepthFirst(node, visited);
        }
        System.out.println("Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!");
    }
}
```

When I reach the node "B" and "E" all the lines before the line System.out.println("Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!") are being skipped.

This is the output I get.

```
Node: A
Visited: [A]
I happened!
A contains [B, E]
Node from adjacencyList: B
Happened!
Node: B
Visited: [A, B]
Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!
I happened!
A contains [B, E]
Node from adjacencyList: E
Happened!
Node: E
Visited: [E, A, B]
Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!
```

How is this possible? Why are the lines inside of the for each loop being skipped when I reach the Node named B or the Node named E?
I know that they don't have any edges connected to eachother, but why is the System.out.println("Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!") line being triggered but not the System.out.println("I happened!") for example? Is my for each going backwards or something? This is so weird, why are my System.out.println's getting ignored except the one after the if statement?

Comment: `How is this possible?` Well since you don't show what appears to be over half your code, there's anything at all could be happening in the methods we don't see.

Comment: What do you mean? I have copy pasted all code involved.

Comment: Because of recursion it is printing recursively because that is the method of computing you are recursively using. In short, you need to understand recursion.

Comment: Thanks man, I thought I understood recursion but this behavior weirded me out. 
I guess I didn't understand it fully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the execution order easier to read by inserting function calls and tabbing those outputs. I hope it helps. You can see that *Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!* is printed equally many times as *I happened!*, so nothing is skipped.

```
traverseDepthFirst(A, #{})

Node: A
Visited: [A]

for node <- B

I happened!
A contains [B, E]
Node from adjacencyList: B
Happened!

    traverseDepthFirst(B, #{A})

    Node: B
    Visited: [A, B]

Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!

for node <- E

I happened!
A contains [B, E]
Node from adjacencyList: E
Happened!

    traverseDepthFirst(E, #{A, B})

    Node: E
    Visited: [E, A, B]

Why are the lines before me not getting printed out?!
```